# Pass variables to a "success" page after processing a form in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Is there anyway to pass context variables to a redirect response? I want to redirect a user to a success page after they submit a form, but I don't want the success page to be just a static html file. I need to display extra information based on the form data.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848715/django-how-to-pass-form-values-to-an-redirected-page) question, but the solution presented there simply renders a different file at the same url. I'd like to redirect the user so that hitting refresh at the page won't submit duplicate entries into the application.

Right now the only thing I have been able to use with some success is redirecting to a url while passing it GET variables as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765887/add-request-get-variable-using-django-shortcuts-redirect). That just seems like a bit of a hack, and was just wondering if there is any better solution...

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about storing your values in a session, then have the redirected page pick up the values from there?

Answer (score 5):

The way I see it you have three options:

1. Use GET variables in the redirect.
2. Store something in the session.
3. If you are creating an object using the form that was submitted, put the id of that object in the redirect url and use it in the new view.

The limitation you are running up against is that http is stateless, not something inherent in django.

Comment: +1 for a thorough answer, sessions should work fine for me. Thank you!